# How to intercept logging messages with Quarkus for testing purposes

Tags: logging, quarkus

Quarkus newbie question: I have a class A that logs something using the default Quarkus logging framework (I believe it is jboss logging). Next I want to write a testclass for A that must be able to verify which logmessages A generated. How can I do this with Quarkus?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `io.quarkus.test.InMemoryLogHandler` and add it to the rootLogger. This will store the logging messages in memory so they can be accessed later at any point.

For an example, please check here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/57fb0cc57bf435bbdb86ca0614bf03dc04bea383

Comment: I started trying to use the approach from the link you provided. However, there is a call being made to inMemoryLogHandler.getRecords(), which is non-existant. Do I have to import a specific version of quarkus-junit5-internal (which contains the InMemoyLogHandler)? I am currently using version 2.0.1.

Comment: Ops. Correct. I had to make `getRecords` public in `InMemoryLogHandler` which is not released yet. I guess, for now, you need to duplicate the class and make it public. Sorry for the inconvenience. It will be out in `2.1.0`.

Comment: Where can I find it nowadays? quarkus-junit5-internal does not exist in 2.16.4.Final

Comment: @syr https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-junit5-internal

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Roberto for your excellent suggestion. However, I started using the LogCaptor library (https://github.com/Hakky54/log-captor) which does an excellent job for my purposes. It just works out of the box without a lot of fuss.

Comment: LogCaptor has the drawback that it brings in Logback-Classic and you would need to replace your classpath for testing. For Unit-Tests this is fine, but when running QuarkusTests you would want to use your production libraries and not something like logback-classic that is only there during test.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has no external dependencies other than the standard Quarkus platform. Also, it's using the default log solution JBoss.

All of the following code was written in **Kotlin** and uses **JUnit 5**.

First, you need a class that extends `java.util.logging.Handler`:

```kotlin
import java.util.logging.Handler
import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.LogRecord

class LogCaptureHandler : Handler() {
    private val capturedMessages: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        level = Level.ALL
    }

    override fun publish(record: LogRecord) {
        capturedMessages.add(record.message)
    }

    override fun flush() {}

    override fun close() {}

    fun getCapturedMessages(): List<String> {
        return capturedMessages.toList()
    }
}
```

Now, in your test, you need to create a `java.util.logging.Logger` variable for the class you want to capture the logs and instantiate a `LogCaptureHandler`:

```kotlin
private val myClassWithLogger = Logger.getLogger("full.package.path.to.ClassWithLogger")
private final val logCaptureHandler = LogCaptureHandler()
```

Also, annotate your test class with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` and configure the setup of the test:

```kotlin
@BeforeAll
fun setup() {
    myClassWithLogger.addHandler(logCaptureHandler)
}
```

Now, in your test method, you can call the method that you want to capture the logs and check if it was logged correctly:

```kotlin
@Test
fun myTestMethod() {
    myClass.methodThatLogs()

    // do the asserts
    assertTrue(logCaptureHandler.getCapturedMessages().size() > 0)
    ...

}
```

Comment: In case you want to capture a SLF4J Logger you have to access the logger via  `org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext.getLogContext().getLogger(name)`